# Make tokens expire

Tags: 7, organic-groups, tokens

Am working on an Organic Group use case where a user can join a group using a one time invitation link sent by email.
How do i make the token attached to the email link expire once its used so that the link will be a onetime only link

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Deep Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/deeplink) module.